# GPU fan spins like crazy in 12.10 on HD 6870

Tags: ati, fan, gpu

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 yesterday on my computer and everything is working fine apart from my GPU fan. For some reason, it spins to what sounds like 100% and just stays there no matter what I do. I dual boot Windows and I use CCC. I keep my fan speed at a constant 50% and the hottest it gets is about 60C which I think is fine. Why is Ubuntu doing this? I was going to install the propriety drivers but I read that they don't work yet. Anyway of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install kernel 3.7.0.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and had the same problem with a 5750 card, constant fan noise seemingly 100% fan speed and high temperature (I've had a maximum of 70 degrees!).

Installing kernel 3.7.0 along with `fglrx` gave me an almost silent computer and a maximum temperature on heavy load of +/- 55 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't really work. I managed to install kernel 3.7.0 but that didn't really do anything and when I went to install `fglrx` directly from the AMD website Unity wouldn't boot up and the graphics seemed very slow as in it took about 5 seconds to move a window. I think i'm close though because the fan is silent at last...

Comment: Have you tried with the software sources fglrx and 3.7.0? (I somehow forgot to mention that's what I'm using.)

Comment: Apparently the `fglrx` in software sources has an incompatibility issue with the version of Xorg Ubuntu uses or something. I tried that before (without updating the kernel) and Xorg wouldn't work. Until `fglrx` gets updated in the software sources it just does this to me.